# Fire function when property value in the object changes

Tags: angularjs

I have array of objects:

[image]

Each object has this properties:

[image]

I need to perform some operations when `IsNormal` property changes in one of the objects above.

I tried this:

```
   $scope.$watch('inspectionReviews.IsNormal', function () {
        //some logic
    })
```

But it doesn't work.

Any idea how I can trigger a function when `IsNormal` property of `inspectionReviews` object changes?

Comment: If you think about it, `inspectionReviews` is an array and `IsNormal` is a prperty on the array item, so is `$scope.inspectionReviews.IsNormal` is even a valid accessor? What triggers a change of `IsNormal` value on the item ?

Comment: @RamisWachtler, checkbox in template triggers a change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a deep watch or use watchCollection.

Deep watch:

```
 $scope.$watch('inspectionReviews', function (newVal, oldVal) { /*...*/ }, true);
```

watchCollection:

```
 $scope.$watchCollection('inspectionReviews', function (newVal, oldVal) { /*...*/ });
```

However, both of them will call the watch function for every change of the collection.

Comment: i guess watchcollection will not work if it is only a property change on the item as it only does a shallow watch

Comment: what is newVal and oldVal?

Comment: the array after and before the change